# how to send emails on local server

Tags: email, mamp

I have Mamp Pro and have a PHP application that sends an email password to someone regestering in  a regester/login system.  I would like to test the email being sent on my local Mamp Pro server but cant figure out how to do it with gmail--it seems a lot of people have this problem with gmail.  Are there any suggestions how I can configure an email account to test this.
Has anyone had this problem also?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code and any server error logs that might indicate any problems sending email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mail()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Well the problem is that Gmail servers reject incoming mail from a local host, so the mail function will not work. That's the whole problem.